# If I ignore an error in a Word document is the error visible to other readers but if I add word to the dictionary, will it show up as mis-spelled?

Tags: ms-word

If I have for example a word like "Hadoop" or some other technical term in a document and I want people reading the document not to see it as an error, I would guess that ignoring the error stays with the document. But if I add "Hadoop" to MS Word's dictionary, I would guess that the word shows up as mis-spelled to another reader. Is there a way where the additions to the dictionary stay with the document?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like turning off checking in Word does not do what you want. If you merely do this, anyone else with the checking on will see your typos or mis-spelled tech terms. Instead, you have to go to each flagged word or sentence and choose "ignore once" (maybe for words mis-spelled you can do "ignore always").